# Powershell ISE: Closing a PowerShell Tab does not unlock a dynamically loaded .NET assembly

Tags: powershell-ise, powershell-5.0

Please consider the following scenario.

- Launch **Windows Powershell ISE** (64 bit)
- Create a new **PowerShell Tab**
- Create a new PS script which loads a custom assembly by invoking 
  **[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom**
- Create an instance of an object from your custom assembly by invoking the **New-Object** command
- Run the script and verify that an instance of your custom object was created.
- Close the **PowerShell Tab**. But, keep PowerShell ISE running. I would have expected PowerShell ISE to have completely unloaded the assembly.

However, the custom assembly is locked until PowerShell ISE is closed down completely.

I am developing a custom .NET library using Visual Studio .NET and PowerShell is a client application of this library. Since closing the Tab does not unlock the assembly, I have to close and re-start Powershell ISE every time I make a change in Visual Studio. This behaviour of PowerShell ISE is drastically slowing down my development time.

Is there a workaround to this issue?

[Loading a custom assembly in ISE through reflection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIDj9.png)

Thanks,
Sau

Comment: If you load a form you should verify you unload it.

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, Just added a picture to better explain my scenario. I am not sure I understand by "unload". I am not creating a Windows Form. Just a plain C# class.  I think the problem would show up even if it were a custom Windows Form because PowerShell has loaded the assembly in its AppDomain. I would have expected PowerShell to unload the AppDomain associated with the PowerShell Tab.

Comment: .NET assemblies cannot be unloaded. The only way to unload an assembly is to tear down the entire AppDomain.

Comment: Hi @DanielB, Thanks for commenting. You are absolutely right. Do you know why PowerShell would not tear down the AppDomain when closing a Tab? I reckon this to be a bug. But, I would be surprised that Microsoft is not aware of this issue.

Comment: PowerShell does not use AppDomains. You can easily check with Process Explorer, in the .NET Assemblies tab of a process.

Comment: Hi @DanielB, Thanks for commenting. From the console of **ISE** I tried out `[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain` and then `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom` 
 and then `[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` which shows my custom assembly .  I am not going to get pedantic about whether or not **PowerShell ISE** partitions itself into AppDomains.  It is my opinion that **ISE** should have a feature of re-setting its environment.  There was something similar in an older non-Microsoft product **PowerGUI** (now discontinued) .

Comment: Hi @DanielB, Did some further experiments. Create multiple **PowerShell  ISE** tabs and run the command  `[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain` in each of them. I found that in each of the Tabs, the Id of the AppDomain was identical. This leads me to conclude that **PowerShell ISE** is indeed not partitioning itself into **AppDomains**.

Comment: AppDomains are very hard to get right, unfortunately. I find it understandable that Microsoft decided not to use them in PowerShell ISE.

Comment: True, "New PowerShell Tab" creates a new PowerShell `Runspace`, not an `AppDomain`.